# Mongoose document type declaration

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I know maybe this is far too basic but I can't recall how to do this properly. I want to declare a Mongoose document to use VS Code IntelliSense for retrieve data.

Right now, `document` is declared as `any` since `findById()` returns `any`:

```js
const document = await MyModel.findById(docId);
```

So, whenever I want to call to something like `document.updateOne()` I don't have intelliSense on.

I have tried using something like:

```js
import { Model, Document } from 'mongoose';
...
const document: Model<Document> = await MyModel.findById(docId);
```

But this don't give me the ability to refer internal attributes directly like `document.title` or any other.

So, what is the proper way to declare `document`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MyModel` has some sort of document type which `extends` the mongoose `Document` type and adds likely adds some properties of its own.  That's the generic that you want to use.

Instead of setting the generic (`<Document>`) when you retrieve the document, you want to set the generic on the `MyModel` object itself so that typescript will infer the correct type for `findById` and for any other methods.  So you want to handle this at the place where you create `MyModel`.

```
interface MyDocument extends Document {
    title: string;
}

const MyModel = mongoose.model<MyDocument>(name, schema);
```

Now the `document` is inferred to be type `MyDocument | null` here:

```
const document = await MyModel.findById(docId);
```

Comment: I did that, but `document` is still `any` type

Comment: Hmm...that should not be the case so I'm not sure what's going wrong.  Can you post a reproducible example in the Typescript Playground or CodeSandbox?  This is what I'm seeing: https://tsplay.dev/oN9Rqm

Comment: Not sure what is wrong... but in the playground actually works: https://tsplay.dev/oN9Rqm

Comment: Well, it should work anyway... So thank you.. I think that is a VS Code issue or something, I did not modify my code to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

The method you mentioned `updateOne` should work out of the box, once you use the `findById` method, at this point in time (Feb 2023).

```
const myDoc = await MyModel.findById(docId);
myDoc.updateOne(/* something */);
```

In case you still have trouble, and need to type the Document elsewhere, I would suggest the `HydratedDocument` and `HydratedDocumentFromSchema` generic types.

```
type Doc1 = HydratedDocument<typeof MyModel>;

type Doc2 = HydratedDocument<typeof MySchema>;
// or
type Doc2 = HydratedDocument<typeof MyModela.schema>;
```

You can use any of these depending on what symbols you have available to you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
export const findPostById = async (postId: any): Promise<HydratedDocument<typeof Post.schema.obj>> => {
    const post = await Post.findById(postId);
    return (post as HydratedDocument<typeof Post.schema.obj>);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The new recommended way of typing documents is using `HydratedDocument`:

```
import {  HydratedDocument } from "mongoose";

interface Animal {name: string}

const animal: HydratedDocument<Animal> = AnimalModel.findOne( // ...
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html